# ppa:mozillateam/ppa gone?

Tags: apt, 22.04, firefox, ppa, mozilla

I am trying to install firefox in a arm64 Ubuntu 22.04 Docker container from the mozillateam ppa, but it seems not to be available anymore. I also could not find it searching it manually at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas.

**Is the ppa really gone?**

```
root@efb6e2e122ee:/home# add-apt-repository -y ppa:mozillateam/ppa             
PPA publishes dbgsym, you may need to include 'main/debug' component
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
Mozilla Team's Firefox stable + 115 ESR and Thunderbird 115 stable builds

Support for Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 ESM is included.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Adding repository.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa.gpg with fingerprint 0AB215679C571D1C8325275B9BDB3D89CE49EC21
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I experience the same issue in my x86_64 Ubuntu 22.04 VM.
I also get a 503 when I try to do

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
```

of [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) that seems to exist certainly. Maybe there currently is an issue with launchpad?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ppa.launchpad.net is currently down according to the [Canonical Status Page](https://status.canonical.com/#/incident/KNms6QK9ewuzz-7xUsPsNylV20jEt5kyKsd8A-3ptQG-R6bil1_KnGrNhlmDfGeBqxPulG7NPS3y2X0ZcEptVQ==).

This should be a temporary issue that should be resolved soon(ish).